# POSTGRES/FTS: How do you match more than one tsvector?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

a "programming languages" database needs to be queried using full-text-search.

```sql
Table "public.ProgrammingLanguages"
   Column    |   Type   | Collation | Nullable |                                                     Default
-------------+----------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 lang        | text     |           | not null |
 lang_search | tsvector |           |          | generated always as (setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(lang, ''::text)), 'A'::"char")) stored
Indexes:
    "ProgrammingLanguages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (lang)
```

Unfortunately this matches only one row if the input is "java" (matches programming language java) and no matches if input is "javasc".

What I need is it to match "javasc" or even "jav" to "javascript".

How to go about this?

I used this query:

```sql
SELECT lang, ts_rank("lang_search", websearch_to_tsquery('javasc')) as rank
FROM "ProgrammingLanguages"
WHERE "lang_search" @@ websearch_to_tsquery('javasc');
```